# Styled Component Custom CSS in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, jsx, styled-components

I'm actually having trouble doing CSS with the styled component in React. Given below is the code snippet

```
import React from 'react';
import { Navbar, Container, Row, Col } from 'reactstrap';
import styled from 'styled-components';

const Styles = styled.div`
  .navbar {
    background-color: black;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .h1 {
    color: white;
  }
`;

const Footer = () => {
  return (
    <Styles>
      <Navbar>
        <Container>
          <Row>
            <Col sm={{ size: 4 }}>
              <h1>Hi</h1>
            </Col>
          </Row>
        </Container>
      </Navbar>
    </Styles>
  );
};

export default Footer;
```

What I want to do is to change the color of the `h1` tag to white but the above custom CSS is not working. I've tried `background-color` too, but still the issue persists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `styled-components`, you shouldn't use classes for styling elements. You should use separated wrappers for components, it's the main point. I think you wanted to do something like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Navbar, Container, Row, Col } from 'reactstrap';
import styled from 'styled-components';

const StyledNavbar = styled(Navbar)`
  background-color: black;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
`;

const Header = styled.h1`
  color: white;
`;

const Footer = () => {
  return (
    <StyledNavbar>
      <Container>
        <Row>
          <Col sm={{ size: 4 }}>
            <Header>Hi</Header>
          </Col>
        </Row>
      </Container>
    </StyledNavbar>
  );
};

export default Footer;
```

Comment: So is it not possible without defining another variable, i.e ```Header```?

Comment: @Nimrod but why? It's the main point of `styled-components`.

Answer (score 1):

you used `.h1` the class, not `h1` the tag, in your css.

https://styled-components.com/docs/basics#pseudoelements-pseudoselectors-and-nesting

Comment: Can you give more details on the solution please, I'm new to CSS

Comment: .h1 as a class would be something like `<h1 class"h1">hi</h1>`. classes are selectors /attributes on a tag. this tag is an h1

Comment: Using styled.h1 needs me to define another variable, is it not possible to define it in styled.div? I only need to change the color.

Comment: ok, I added ```classname='h1'```, but it still didn't work.

Comment: actually sorry I don't think you need another variable I'll remove that. see my comment above